# How do I create an anonymous list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I know that in c# 4 or 4.5 you can create anonymous types and dynamic types, but I am not sure how it works.
I am iterating over a sharepoint site collections and I want to add for each subsite an item to the list, with 3 columns

However I dont want to create a class for this because its only specific to this method.

```
private void RenderGrid()
{
    string currentUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;
    List<object> listobject= new List<object>();

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPSite clientSiteCollection = new SPSite(currentUrl))
        {
            foreach (SPWeb web in clientSiteCollection.AllWebs)
            {
                string webtemplate = web.Properties["WebTemplate"];

                if (webtemplate.Equals("xx"))
                {
                    SPList xx = web.Lists.TryGetList(Constants.Lists.xx);

                    if (opportunityInfoList != null)
                    {
                        opportunityInfo.Add(new object() {
                            col1 = "value1",
                            col2 = "value2",
                            col3 = "value3"
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    lastCreatedOpportunitiesGrid.DataSource = opportunityInfo;
    lastCreatedOpportunitiesGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your anonymous type by not giving a specific type in your `new` statement:

```
opportunityInfo.Add(new {
    col1="value1",
    col2="value2",
    col3= "value3"});
```

This will work, but you won't be able to use properties like `opportunityInfo[0].col1` because you've declared that list explicitly as `List<object>`.  If you instead declare it as `List<dynamic>` you'll be able to access the members of the anonymous class.

(Note: I'm not sure offhand how the data binding will work with the anonymous type, or whether the type of the `List` will make any behavioural difference.)

Comment: after this, I can use the boundColumn in the gridview?

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure.  You'll have to try that for yourself!

Comment: it says Type Expected in the first opening parenthesis

Comment: shouldn't it just be `new { col1 = "val"...}`?

Answer (score 1):

Anonymouse don't have name.

just create new class without name and that will be your anonymouse object.

```
  opportunityInfo.Add(new  {
                            col1 = "value1",
                            col2 = "value2",
                            col3 = "value3"
                        });
```

Comment: this does not compile. you do not include parens after `new` when generating anonymous objects. when you include them, the compiler expects you to supply a type as well.